# REST standard security

Tags: security, rest, bitcoin

https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

Is it normal to essentially pass your username and password in the URL of an http.post? I'm using the blockchain.info api to send and receive bitcoin transactions on my website. Everything works, but I'm still uneasy about how their service is set up to send out payments. Seems vulnerable?

Comment: Normal REST APIs send it through HTTP headers, typically the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Base URL for all requests: https://blockchain.info/fr/merchant/$guid/.

The API endpoints are available through [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), so every bit of data you send there (including the URL) is encrypted and protected from [man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks, I'd say this is safe enough.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't normal, but it will be encrypted as it is sent over [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Usernames and passwords in the address are usually avoided as URLs are often logged on their journey (e.g. by servers, proxies and browsers) but only systems that have a certificate trusted by your client machine can view the full URL over HTTPS (only source and destination will be exposed on the way).